# Rails4 Timezone-Argument out of range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I just upgraded to Rails 4 & Ruby 2.0 (from a Rails 3.2.17 & Ruby 1.9.3) and now my unix timestamp conversion is failing both in specs and in the console.

I convert time from the client such as (`"1393371868"`) as shown below. I verify that the conversion is correct (`2014-02-25 23:44:28 UTC`) but just before the record is saved an exception is thrown. This all worked before the upgrade. Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
raw_value = post_date_before_type_cast  
self[:post_date] = Time.at(raw_value.to_i).utc


ArgumentError: argument out of range
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:286:in `initialize'
```

Comment: this works on my machine, with a similar environment

Comment: Check to make sure that `raw_value` has a proper vale.

Comment: Raw value is fine. I use a before_validation to convert the string to the date as shown above. This all is triggered from the controller via  **current_user.comments.build(params)** with   params = {"post_date"=>"1393371868", "content"=>"et", ...}